# xlwings: how can I read all values when first cell is empty?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am using xlwings and I have a problem.

my excel data looks like:
[image: my excel data]

Like above a image, My data has a empty value of first cell.

when I try to read that column...I have all NaN values...like below..

```
Resolution Type

 NaN 

 NaN 

 NaN 

 NaN
```

This is my code..

`sheet.range('G1').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, expand='table', headers=True).value`

I want to my original data..

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

use [used_range](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Sheet.used_range):

```
import xlwings as xw

filepath = r"a_file.xlsx"

wb = xw.Book(filepath)
sheet = wb.sheets[0]

print(sheet.used_range)
```